# Displaying openCV's windows

Tags: opencv, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I made a program on OpenCV that used fonctions like "NamedWindow" wich display a window with GTK, or Qt, etc..
Now in my ROS program, "autopilote.cpp" i've included "<opencv2/opencv.hpp>" and put my OpenCV code into it. It seems to correctly get the video capture, analyse it, and correctly publish results. But no windows are displaying. And I can't see somes errors or warning about this.
Have you got somes advices to display the windows ? Is this feature enabled in opencv in ros ? Should I create windows in another way ?
Thanks you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/162846/displaying-opencv%27s-windows/) by [AntKa](https://answers.ros.org/users/17781/antka/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-05-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you included opencv's waitKey command after updating the windows?

From opencv user interface docs on the waitKey function:

> This function is the only method in HighGUI that can fetch and handle events, so it needs to be called periodically for normal event processing unless HighGUI is used within an environment that takes care of event processing.

---

Originally posted by [tparmelee](https://answers.ros.org/users/17786/tparmelee/) with karma: 36 on 2014-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2